# how implement lazy loading material table react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, lazy-loading, material-table

hi i want to ask how to implement [material table](https://material-table.com/#/) with lazy loading ? is that possible?

currently im using pagination button but customer want to change to via scroll.or maybe it can implement both.

```
 <MaterialTable
    components={{
      Cell: props => (
        <MTableCell
          onDragStart={e => e.preventDefault()}
          
          onContextMenu={e => {
            handleEvent(e, props.rowData.tableData.id, props.rowData);
          }}
          {...props}
        />
        ),
      //current custom pagination via button
       Pagination: MTprops => (
        <TablePagination
            {...MTprops}
            
            count={props.pageCount.total}
            page={props.pageCount.current}
            rowsPerPage={props.pageCount.limit}
            onChangePage={(e, newPageNumber) => handlePageChange(e, newPageNumber, MTprops)}
            onChangeRowsPerPage={(e) => {handleRowsPerPageChange(e, MTprops); }}
            ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
        />
        ),
      Container: props => <Paper {...props} elevation={0} />
    }}
```